# subreports variable not working in parent report

Tags: crystal-reports

I made a report using Crystal Reports and I have two sub reports in it which have some money transactions data and they are calculating specific type of transactions amount on parent report I have to show the grand total of all transactions, but I get an error while accessing the sub reports variables.

I am just accessing those variables by their names and I initialize them as `global` in sub reports. How can I fix my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its better for you to code your formula here but after understanding your problem I can suggest you to initialize `SubReport`'s variable as `shared` instead of `global` which you want to use in Parent Report.

Comment: I should provide code it first but `shared` keyword worked . Thanks alot.